# AngularJS service PUT to flat JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs

This is perhaps a stupid question.  In which case I apologize.

I know you can use http.get to read flat JSON files, but is there any way to use a flat JSON file in a angular service to mimic a database for other CRUD operations.  This would be very basic and only in development.  I plan on using django rest, firebase, or something similar, but wanted to focus on the front end first.

Comment: ngResource was the first thing I tried

Comment: Did you look at the `Post` or `Put` examples there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$httpBackend` service from the `ngMockE2E` to mock a complete backend with post, get, put, and so on.

I've included the example from the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) for the sake of completeness:

```
myAppDev = angular.module('myAppDev', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
myAppDev.run(function($httpBackend) {
  var phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}];

  // returns the current list of phones
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);

  // adds a new phone to the phones array
  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data) {
    var phone = angular.fromJson(data);
    phones.push(phone);
    return [200, phone, {}];
  });

  $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/templates\//).passThrough();
  //...
});
```